# add button components dynamically and get values emitted back to parent

Tags: angular

I am stuck at getting data from a child component that was dynamically rendered by parent component.

Child.component.html:

```
   <span>Side: {{random_side}}</span>
   <button (click)="submitSide(random_side)">Save</button>
```

Child.component.ts:

```
      @Output() eventPassGeneratedSide=new EventEmitter<number>();

      random_side:number=0;

      submitSide(side:number){
       //button clicked. Send data to parent
       this.eventPassGeneratedSide.emit({'side':side});
       }

       onNgInit(){
        this.random_side=Math.floor( Math.random() * 12 );

        }
```

Now I am creating the component dynamically in my parent component since user can generate as many random sides as he pleases.

parent.component.html

```
   <ng-template #generated_side></ng-template>
   <button (click)="generateNewSide()">Generate</button>
```

parent.component.ts

```
 @ViewChild('generated_side', {read: ViewContainerRef}) generated_side: ViewContainerRef; //generated child component will go here
  sidesComponent;


 handleSubmittedValue($event){
 //when button in child component is clicked, $event is populated so parent can do something with it.

 //ERROR: THIS NEVER FIRES
console.log($event)
   }


   onNgInit(){

         this.sidesComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(childComponent);
```

}

```
  generateNewSide(){



    let instance:any=this.generated_side.createComponent(this.sidesComponent);

     instance.instance.eventPassGeneratedSide.subscribe(this.handleSubmittedValue);

  //eventPassGeneratedSide is output variable in Child Component that is supposed to emit avalues to hanldeSubmittedValue
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> DynamicComponentLoader does not support inputs or outputs

Ref This:https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6326

If you want to share data between child and parent use Subject or BehaviourSubject

Create a Service and define variable type of subject

**Service.ts**

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
  eventPassGeneratedSide= new Subject();
```

**Child.ts**

```
constructor(private service:Service);
 submitSide(side:number){
       //button clicked. Send data to parent
       this.service.eventPassGeneratedSide.next({side:'side'})
}
```

**Parent.ts**

```
handleSubmittedValue($event){
this.service.eventPassGeneratedSide.subscribe(data=>console.log(data))
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @Chellappan. I am a little lost on the parent's part. How do we call the hanldeSubmittedValue(). I have put the line in onNgInit, hoping it listens for incoming messages constantly or something but nothing is output in the console. Simply put: how do I recieve what Child.ts puts with .next() method in my Parent.ts?